# Exportar Datatables

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-datatables, datatable, exportação

Eu utilizo o plugin [JQuery Datatables](http://datatables.ne), e gostaria de exportar os dados (CSV, Excel, PDF...) das tabelas através de botões personalizados, ao invés dos botões que o próprio plugin oferece, será que é possível?

No retângulo vermelho, os botões do próprio Datatables. Gostaria de adicionar um botão ao lado dos botões que estão no retângulo azul e chamar algum método para exportar os dados da tabela.

[image: No retângulo vermelho os botões do próprio Datatables. Gostaria de adicionar um botão ao lado dos botões que estão no retângulo azul]

Código que faz os botões nativos do Datatables aparecer:

```
                <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 btn-acao-grid">
                   <button  class="btn btn-success btn-sm margin-btn" id="add">
                      <span><i class="icon wb-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Adicionar</span>
                    </button> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 btn-acao-grid">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm margin-btn">
                      <span><i class="icon wb-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Alterar</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 btn-acao-grid">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm margin-btn" >
                      <span><i class="icon wb-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-6 btn-acao-grid pesq-refresh">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-dark btn-sm margin-btn" id="btn-pesquisa">
                      <span><i class="icon wb-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span>
                   </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-6 btn-acao-grid pesq-refresh" >
                   <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-dark btn-sm margin-btn" id="btn-refresh" >
                      <span><i class="icon wb-reload" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span>
                   </button>
                </div>
           </div> 



<table id="example" class="display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>$205,500</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Shou Itou</td>
            <td>Regional Marketing</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>$163,000</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>

       <script>
       $("#example").DataTable( {
                    dom: "Bfrtip",
                    buttons: [
                        "copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print"
                    ],
                    "scrollY": 400,
                    "scrollX": true,
                    "searching": false,
                    columnDefs:[{
                        orderable: false,
                        className: "select-checkbox",
                        targets:   0
                    }],
                  select: {
                      style:    "os",
                      selector: "td:first-child"
                  },
                  order: [
                            [ 1, "asc" ]
                  ]
                }); 
          </script>
```

Gostaria de exportar os dados deste Datatables não pelos botões nativos dele, mas sim por um botão, que poderia ser adicionado acima do grid com a opção exportar.

O Datatables possui alguma função para exportar seus dados, que poderia ser chamado através dos botões acima do grid (em azul)?

Comment: Carlos, a sua questão é muito abrangente, falta mostar parte de seu código, como tentou resolver isso para podermos te ajudar? Faça o Tour e leia o Ajuda aqui do Soft, depois edite sua questão detalhando mais e sendo mais claro e objetivo. Bem vindo!

Comment: Eu sou novato aqui. Adicionei os códigos

Comment: @CarlosEduardoScheffer antes de uma olhada aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour caso já não tenha visto!

Comment: Eu só quero saber se o Datatables possui alguma função para exportar seus dados, mas que possa ser chamado através de botões externos, de meu próprio código. É possível ou não?

Answer (score 1):

> O Datatables possui alguma função para exportar seus dados, que poderia ser chamado através dos botões acima do grid (em azul)?

Em resumo, sim, mas você possivelmente [terá que criar seus próprios botões se a função que você quer ainda não existe](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/custom).

Se a ideia é controlar a *Data Table* através de botões externos, [há uma série de eventos que você pode usar](https://datatables.net/reference/event/) para criar botões em qualquer lugar da página e disparar comandos para a *Data Table* usando JavaScript.